How to find where values for variables used in a function come from?
How do I identify what numbers are being given to the variable cpi?
I looked in all other modules and couldn't find anything like a Dim cpi as... or something like it.
Function cumcpi(om, time, cpi)

    cumcpi = 1
   
    If time > om Then
        For C = om To time - 1
            cumcpi = cumcpi * (1 + cpi(C))
        Next
    End If

End Function


cpi is the third argument of the function. "What actual numbers are being given" depends on how cumcpi is being called elsewhere.

Search for instances of x = cumcpi(a, b, c) in other modules. Here, x, a, b, and c are placeholders; the actual code may use different variables.

There are other functions that calls for cumcpi but they always use the same notation, being: cumcpi(om, time, cpi) and I cant find anywhere whats cpi and what numbers are going into it

The number in cpi will be whatever number is passed to it when cumcpi is called.
For instance, if you call cumcpi like this: cumcpi(7, 8, 9), then cpi will equal 9.
It doesn't matter if there is a Dim cpi somewhere else. What matters is that in this function, cpi will equal whatever value is getting passed to it when cumcpi is called.
Lastly, cumcpi, om, time, and cpi should ideally all by defined at the top of the function, like so:
Function cumcpi(om as Long, time as Long, cpi as Long) as Long '[assuming they all need to be Long... define them however you need to.]
